# (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 42703 (undefined_column) column c0.users_id does not exist

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework

My action failed with column c0.users_id does not exist
hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "c0.user_id". I had checked but not sure what's wrong. here is my code below.

```
defmodule Test.Accounts.User do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset
  alias Test.Accounts.Credential
  schema "users" do
    field :name, :string
    field :username, :string
    has_one :credential, Credential
    timestamps()
  end

defmodule Test.Accounts.Credential do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset
  alias Test.Accounts.User
  schema "credentials" do
    field :email, :string
    field :user_id, :id
    belongs_to :users, User

    timestamps()
  end
```

My schema for both User and credential

```
defmodule Test.Repo.Migrations.CreateUsers do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:users) do
      add :name, :string
      add :username, :string

      timestamps()
    end

    create unique_index(:users, [:username])
  end
end


defmodule Test.Repo.Migrations.CreateCredentials do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:credentials) do
      add :email, :string
      add :user_id, references(:users, on_delete: :delete_all),
          null: false

      timestamps()
    end

    create unique_index(:credentials, [:email])
    create index(:credentials, [:user_id])
  end
end
```

Please can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
field :user_id, :id
belongs_to :users, User
```

in your `Credenial` definition. Either remove `belongs_to` or remove `field :user_id` and change `belongs_to :users, User` to `belongs_to :user, User` (singular).

Comment: Why is it :user (singular) instead of :users? Is it supposed to be defined in Phoenix library somewhere?

Comment: It is relationship name, not database table name.

Comment: So in what module is the relationship name defined? or is it just by convention?

Answer (score 0):

I would remove `field :user_id, :id` and make sure you didn't run your migration file BEFORE you made any changes. Just to be sure you can try to reset your database and see if you still have the same issue.